# How to override localizedDescription for custom Error in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, inheritance, swift3

Error protocol [has only one](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/error) property localizedDescription.
I tried to create custom object inherited from NSObject and Error but I can not override localizedDescription. How can I do that?

This code does not allow me to get custom description:

```
class MyError: NSObject, Error {
    var desc = ""
    init(str: String) {
        desc = str
    }
    override var description: String {
        get {
            return "MyError: \(desc)"
        }
    }
   var localizedDescription: String {
        get {
            return self.description
        }
    }
}

func test_my_code() {
    let error = MyError(str: "my test string")
    let x = error as Error
    print(x.localizedDescription)
}
```

Calling function "test_my_code" get unexpected result:
"The operation couldn’t be completed...".

What should I do to get result "MyError: my test string" ?

Comment: Won't you need `override`?

Comment: can't you extend Error with a new property and then read that instead?

Comment: @SunilChauhan no. Anything from protocol should not be overridden. Adding `override` will break compilation.

Comment: @Honey I do not want to extend protocol. I just want to make my custom class which conforms Error protocol.

Comment: @Speakus oops, missed that.!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The documentation about new Error bridging feature is not clear enough still now, so this answer may need some updates in the near future, but according to [SE-0112](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0112-nserror-bridging.md) and the [latest Swift source code](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/NSError.swift), you may need to use `LocalizedError` rather than `Error` and implement `errorDescription`.

```
class MyError: NSObject, LocalizedError {
    var desc = ""
    init(str: String) {
        desc = str
    }
    override var description: String {
        get {
            return "MyError: \(desc)"
        }
    }
    //You need to implement `errorDescription`, not `localizedDescription`.
    var errorDescription: String? {
        get {
            return self.description
        }
    }
}

func test_my_code() {
    let error = MyError(str: "my test string")
    let x = error as Error
    print(x.localizedDescription)
}
test_my_code() //->MyError: my test string
```

---

Other than using `LocalizedError`, this default implementation works:

(NSError.swift, the link shown above)

```
public extension Error {
    /// Retrieve the localized description for this error.
    var localizedDescription: String {
        return NSError(domain: _domain, code: _code, userInfo: nil).localizedDescription
    }
}
```

It is a little complicated how Swift defines `_domain` or `_code` from arbitrary types just conforming to `Error`, but it seems that `NSError` generates "The operation couldn’t be completed..." for unknown combinations of domain and code.

Comment: Perfect! I was struggling with this and made ugly switch/cases. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 18):

If custom type conforms to protocol `CustomStringConvertible` and provides localized `description`, then the following extension of `LocalizedError` might be useful:

```
extension LocalizedError where Self: CustomStringConvertible {

   var errorDescription: String? {
      return description
   }
}
```

Example code:

```
class MyError: LocalizedError, CustomStringConvertible {

   let desc: String

   init(str: String) {
      desc = str
   }

   var description: String {
      let format = NSLocalizedString("Operation error: %@", comment: "Error description")
      return String.localizedStringWithFormat(format, desc)
   }
}


let error = MyError(str: "my test string")
let x = error as Error
print(x.localizedDescription) // Prints "Operation error: my test string"
print(String(describing: x))  // Prints "Operation error: my test string"
```

Comment: This is the best answer here. Seriously, conform to `CustomStringConvertible` and provide the `var description: String`.